# How to render my ejs view with response image from node js

Tags: node.js, gridfs, nodejs-stream

I am using gridfs and mongoDB to store images in chunks. And whenever a user requests my server just sends a streamlined image file in response by piping.

Currently my code looks like this :

```
const download = async (req, res)=>{
try{
const fileName = req.params.name

await mongoClient.connect();

const database = mongoClient.db(dbConfig.database)
const bucket = new GridFsBucket(database, { // required for important methods like openDownloadStream
  bucketName:dbConfig.imgBucket
})

const downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(fileName);

downloadStream.pipe(res) // it only displays an jpg/png image
// res.render("image") , I want to render this ejs page with a image in it and with some static content in it. I want to stream image
 } catch(err){
res.status(501).render("error",{error: err})
}}
```

My output looks like :
[my code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1LQy.png)

It only renders a jpg file, like how above link is working see it.
but rather what i want to do is to get image from response object and render it with my other html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do too much at once.

You need to de-couple the desired streaming image from the initial rendering of your template.  Include an image tag in your tempalte with a distinct api from which the image will stream, and the result will look something like your example.

Say your image is called `test.png`, your server `index.js`, and your ejs teplate `index.ejs`.  The template (for the sake of your question) can be very simple: `index.ejs`-->

```
<h1> stream that image below! </h1>
<image src="/image" hieght="200px" width="200px";/>
```

Notice the `src` of this image - this will hit a distinct api on your backend that will stream the image.

The server `index.js` will look like this -->

```
var exp = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var app = exp();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/image", (req, res) => {
  const streamReadFile = fs.createReadStream("test.png");
  streamReadFile.pipe(res);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("listening on *:8080");
});
```

Notice here at the home route you render the template as

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});
```

The src in the image of your template then makes a request back to the server, hitting the `/image` route which will stream the desired image to your html

```
app.get("/image", (req, res) => {
  const streamReadFile = fs.createReadStream("test.png");
  streamReadFile.pipe(res);
});
```

[Here's a working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-express-ejs-forked-gi5edg?file=/src/index.js) of the example above, where your image is streamed to an ejs template.